# Why does distinct does not give results in the order?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I ordered my results by their id's by:

```
    CREATE TABLE my_table2 AS SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY record_group_id;
```

now when i execute:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT record_group_id  FROM my_table2 where rownum <=1000000;
```

I get gorup id's in random order, though my order by went fine:
Here is few of the records in result set

```
1599890050
1647717203
1647717120
1647717172
1647716972
1647717196
1647717197
1647717205
1599889999
1599889986
```

What could be the possible reason?
Shouldn't DISTINCT statement return records in same order as they are in table?

Comment: try with ORDER BY command

Comment: Use ORDER BY on your SELECT statement: `SELECT DISTINCT record_group_id  FROM my_table2 where rownum <=1000000 ORDER BY record_group_id;`

Comment: But shouldn't the SELECT statement return distinct records in order as they come(which should by sorted as they had been sorted before)

Comment: Table's don't *have* any guaranteed order. If you want a particular order, you have to specify it on the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I didn't get you , forgive me for my lack of knowledge but ORDER BY statement in the first queryt would produce the new table in a sorted record_group_id right ?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the first statement controls the order in which results are returned. However, there's **no** guarantee that the order in which you insert rows into a table will be the same order in which rows are *returned* from a table in any subsequent select statement. And even if there *were* such a guarantee, you're saying "please select rows from this table, make them distinct (by some unknown means) and then return the distinct values" - well, one way to make rows distinct is to sort them (by any column(s) of the server's choosing).

Comment: @David: Even if the records are stored in a specific order, there is no guarantee that you will get them in that order when you use a query to fetch them.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: How can i make sure for one , that the data I inserted in the first table is inserted after being sorted(or is ordered)  acc to the record_group_id? Or there no way i can make sure of that ?

Comment: I don't know how many different ways we can explain to you that any actual/implied order of the data contained in `my_table2` has *no* guaranteed ordering effects on subsequent queries. You can keep shifting *how* you ask your question, but it doesn't affect the actual situation.

Comment: thanks i got it ! its just that I did this to de-fragment(as i retrieved records group wise) my tables and wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Neither `SELECT` or `DISTINCT` defines the order of data.

If you want ordered data explicitly define the `Order` you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT record_group_id 
FROM my_table2 
WHERE rownum <=1000000 
ORDER BY record_group_id;
```

Comment: So in this case(the one i have mentioned above) the execution planner would take first 1000000 records from table and return their group id's in random manner ?

Comment: I think you should read @Guffa 's answer, as it explains why.

Answer (score 3):

The ordering only determines the order of the source data that is inserted in the table. If there is no clustered index in the table, that means that the records will be stored in that order physically.

However, how the records are stored doesn't guarantee that they will be selected in that order. The execution planner determines the most efficient way to run the query, which means that the data might not be fetched the way that you think it is, and it can differ from time to time as the data changes, or just the statistics about the data.

For a simple query like in the example, you usually get a predictable result, but there is no guarantee, so you always need to sort the query where you fetch the data to be sure to get a predictable result.

One reason that you don't get the data in the order that they are stored in the table in this case, may be that an index is used for filtering the result, and the records are returned in the order of the index rather than the order of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use ORDER BY on your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT record_group_id
FROM my_table2
WHERE rownum <=1000000
ORDER BY record_group_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `DISTINCT` has no effect on order, only on uniqueness of values.

If you want to control order too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT record_group_id
FROM my_table2
WHERE rownum <= 1000000
ORDER BY record_group_id -- Added this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that data in the table is ordered is wrong.
There is *no* implicit ordering in a database table - it's just a bag of unsorted data.

If you need ordered data, you'll have to use ORDER BY - there's no way around it (neither DISTINCT nor GROUP BY nor ...), see [TomKyte Blog on Order By](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/08/order-in-court.html)